# What is this wax seal used by Eddard Stark in "You Win or You Die"?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Season 1 Episode 7 of *Game of Thrones*, Ned Stark writes a letter bound for Stannis Baratheon and seals it with the following wax seal.

[image: wax seal used by Ned Stark]

What, if anything, does this wax seal represent?

I assume it must have some significance, otherwise it would not be given this close-up shot.

Comment: Good question. It's not [the Stark seal](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/UwkAAMXQ1ZhTfVUX/s-l400.jpg), nor that of [the Hand of the King](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/418-N7fdx6L._SX258_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**It's a direwolf and just another representation of House Stark.**

It's obviously not the official Stark sigil as mentioned by *rand al-thor*.

[image: Stark sigil]

*The official Stark sigil: A grey direwolf on a white field*

However the Starks do use other imagery:

[image: Another Stark sigil]

[image: Another Stark sigil]

In the episode [Mockingbird](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Mockingbird), *Hot Pie* creates a loaf of bread in the shape of a direwolf to represent House Stark. **The bread is actually very similar to the one in the wax.**

[image: A loaf of bread in the shape of a direwolf]

Therefore I think that the Starks use many direwolf shapes as their official mascot. This stamp is no different.

Comment: Good find! I did not realize they used other imagery besides the house sigil in official capacity (e.g. banners or shield crests).

Comment: @Argenture Keep in mind that a house sigil is not as strictly defined as a modern-day corporate logo. Anything resembling a direwolf fits the bill; there's no specific rendering that's considered "official".

Comment: Also I would imagine that seals would often be specific to an individual. eg two people in house stark may need to identify themselves. They might both have the wolf imagery but they'd need to be different to differentiate the two people.

Comment: I think @Chris has got it. Seals were used like signatures, since writing was usually delegated to scribes (real life) or maesters (TV show). If every Stark had an identical seal, there'd be nothing stopping, say, Sansa sending a letter saying "Please deliver 200 lemon cakes urgently, by order of the Hand of the King". Nice attention to detal by the production team there...

Comment: Why haven't we seen a shadow cat?

Comment: Fun fact: during the Sengoku Jidai period Japanese house seals were calligraphy! They were drawn by hand with ink on paper so no two seals are identical and they vary by the skill, personality and emotional state of the artist. Some houses even have official variants of seals. I don't know if it's the same for european coat of arms but at least in real life the Japanese used seals in similar way to GoT.

Answer (score 11):

To be honest it looks a bit like a stylized map of Blackwater Bay (rotated), with Dragonstone and Driftmark being the main islands in the bay.

Some of the details are definitely off, but that could be consistent with imperfect maps and perhaps some distortion in the making of the seal and then some more in the way the seal came out this time, the angle we're looking at it being shot from, and so on.

It might well be a wolf as the first answer indicated (I finally figured out the intent would be a wolf facing left in the picture), but the first impression I had was of islands in a bay.

---

Edit: after playing about with the images for a bit, I've come to the conclusion that it is just as Rowan Freeman suggested:

[image]

So while I now think Rowan's answer is likely correct and my suggestion here is likely wrong, I'll leave this here, at least for now.

Comment: Nice comparison. The two are very close except for the tail.

Comment: @Rowan Even the tail is pretty close, really. If you take the top image and curl the tail up a little tighter so it almost touches and then "thicken"/blur the whole outline of the wolf a bit so the space in the loop made by the tail shrinks some -- it's not that much of a distortion -- then they would look quite close. Similarly you need to blur/thicken the legs, which would make the raised spaces between them smaller, and move the frontmost hind leg just a little forward. It's weird, at first I couldn't see a wolf *at all*, but once I played with it a little and saw it, now I can't unsee it.

Comment: The seal marker, in wood, wouldn't leave a perfect impression, in soft wax. Pressure applied, any sideways movement, how flow-y the wax is, etc. That explains the differences. That image is why I'm voting this up.

Comment: @cde indeed, just such a "blurring" of the impression would be expected. Allowing for that the differences are small.